# How to compile Poco with cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, poco, poco-libraries

I have Downloaded the POCO from the mirror site and when I am compiling the it not able to link the library ?
Example

```
#include "Poco/Timestamp.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <ctime>
using Poco::Timestamp;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   Timestamp now; // the current date and time
   std::time_t t1 = now.epochTime(); // convert to time_t ...
   Timestamp ts1(Timestamp::fromEpochTime(t1)); // ... and back again
   for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) ; // wait a bit
   Timestamp::TimeDiff diff = now.elapsed(); // how long did it take?
   Timestamp start(now); // save start time
   now.update(); // update with current
   time
   diff = now - start; // again, how long?
   return 0;
 }
```

compilation error

```
$ g++ pocoDemo.cpp
      pocoDemo.cpp:1:10: fatal error: Poco/Timestamp.h: No such file or directory
      compilation terminated.
```

Comment: How are you configuring the package and running the build ?

Comment: g++ needs to know where to look for your Poco header files.  Usually do this with the -I option.  Also keep in mind that this is not a problem with "linking the library".  That comes later, after compilation.